# How can I get a list of tests or tasks from a locust?

Tags: python, locust

I have a locustfile with a set of test cases (@task). Is there any CLI option available so that I can parse the locust file and get the test cases or tags from it ? Consider the below sample code from https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/basic.py
Here, there is a single test case page404(), determined by @task.

```
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task, between


def index(l):
    l.client.get("/")


def stats(l):
    l.client.get("/stats/requests")


class UserTasks(TaskSet):
    # one can specify tasks like this
    tasks = [index, stats]

    # but it might be convenient to use the @task decorator
    @task
    def page404(self):
        self.client.get("/does_not_exist")


class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    """
    User class that does requests to the locust web server running on localhost
    """

    host = "http://127.0.0.1:8089"
    wait_time = between(2, 5)
    tasks = [UserTasks]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list User classes using `locust -l`, but there is no built in way to list individual tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this to manipulate task weights , don't know if it might help:

```
class MyTaskSet(TaskSet):

    def on_start(self):
        unique_tasks = set(self.tasks)
```

tasks param under TaskSet is a list of weighed tasks, for example if I have 2 tasks one weighing 2 and the other 3 it will be

```
[a,a,b,b,b]
```

so I convert it to set to find unique tasks